# Route on id url

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a table app on angular 2, and now i use a routing to navigate on my page.

I have some click event, and after clicking i am going to another page with another table, something like this (click button):

[image]

And after that i would to set a new adress for any "смотр.", something like this: localhost/sm1, localhost/sm2 ...

How it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

**1 - on the template**

```
<div [routerLink]="['somepath',item.id]"> </div>
```

**2 - on your component**
some click event handler

```
onItemClick(item){
    this.router.navigate(['somepath',item.id]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Tell me please, router is var, or some import component?

Comment: router is injected core module from @angular/router

Comment: and if i get id from API? how syntax this?

Answer (score 0):

You can import Router like this:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

...

```
constructor(
  private router: Router
) {}
```

and use the Mehari's second answer